# How to test socket.setKeepAlive in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I tried to test the function of setKeepAlive() in NodeJS. I ran Server.js and client.js on different machines within same local network. Then, I turned off the wifi connection on the client machine (break the internet connection). After 15 minutes, there is still no message thrown. Why is that? Didn't setKeepAlive() work?

Here is the code of the server and client:

Client.js

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '192.168.0.16';
var PORT = 8333;

var client = net.connect(PORT, HOST, function connected(){
    console.log('connected');
});

client.setKeepAlive(true, 1);
client.write('hi server');

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received' + data);
});

client.on('close', function(){
    console.error('connection closed');
)};

client.on('error', function(err){
    console.error('error', err);
});
```

Server.js

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '192.168.0.16';
var PORT = 8333;

net.createServer(function(sock) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);

    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        sock.write('hi client');
    });

    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' +
        sock.remoteAddress + ' ' + sock.remotePort);
    });

    sock.on('error', function(error){
        console.log('error', error);
    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement keep_alive by myself using both setInterval(sendKeepAliceFunc, delay), and socket.setTimeout()

Delay between keep_alive message should be big enough (~10000ms), it not valid if delay < round trip (?)

I think the original keepalive feature is not reliable. I have success enable it on other programming language (C# and C) and I can trace network and see KEEP_ALIVE packets, but then it NOT work in some circumstances (special network configuration, people may run app in virtual machine, ...)

So I suggest implement it by yourself, you can implement a your own socket with the same APIs but also has your new keepalive feature.

Comment: Actually, I change some codes in 'int uv__tcp_keepalive(int fd, int on, unsigned int delay)' (located in node/deps/uv/src/unix/tcp.c), and it works.

Comment: @ShawnNeal Congratulation! Have you set more options for the socket? I still can not find the problem.

Comment: ye, you'd better call 
`setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, sizeof(on));`
first to enable keepalive, then you can set 
`setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &keepIdle, sizeof(keepIdle));`
`setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &keepInterval, sizeof(keepInterval));`
`setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &keepCount, sizeof(keepCount));`
TCP_KEEPIDLE sets the idle time before sending the probe, TCP_KEEPINTVL and TCP_KEEPCNT defines how the probes are sent

Comment: @ShawnNeal Oh, you can fix that? You should report this to node.js :)

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I am having trouble w/ TCP keep-alive in node v8.9.1. I set `socket.setKeepAlive(true, 10000)` and sent and received some data while watching in WireShark. One minute later the remote host closes the connection with `FIN+ACK `. No keep-alive packets are sent. Furthermore, `socket.write(new Buffer(0))` does not result in any packets being sent, so it appears non-trivial to implement sending an empty packet in a nodejs socket.

Comment: Following-up on my previous comment:
(1) It appears that of the 3 TCP keepalive parameters 'time', 'interval', and 'retry', Node (v8.x) only natively allows control of the first. To adjust the others (on POSIX operating systems) one can use [node-net-keepalive](https://github.com/hertzg/node-net-keepalive) or change the OS default. 
(2) The recommended default value for the initial delay is no less than 2 hours, which was not helpful in my case.
(3) TCP spec does not require keep-alive to be implemented
(4) Node's `Net.socket.setKeepAlive` did not set initialDelay correctly (bug?)

Comment: Regarding (4) in my previous comment, it is only partly correct. Calling `setKeepAlive` after the connection is established has no effect, but calling it right after `net.connect(...)`, for example, does seem to work after all. Since I did not see any mention of this constraint in the documentation I believed it to be an implementation bug. Now I think it's just a shortcoming of the current documentation .

Comment: grr, I must be crazy. Disregard (4) entirely. When I tested it further (preparing to submit bug report) I could not reproduce the problem I encountered before. It must have been my goof. OK, I'm done commenting now. Sorry for all the chatter.