# How to detect if net.Socket connection dies - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

### Background

I am communicating with a machine using [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) via TCP/IP.

I am able to establish the connection and to send and receive packets of Buffers, which is all fine.

### Problem

The problem is that if I manually disconnect the internet cable from the machine, my Node.js connection doesn't fire the `close` event and I have no means to know if something failed!

### Code

```
let socket;

const start = async function ( config ) {

    await connecToBarrier( config )
        .then( () => console.log( "connected to barrrier" ) )
        .catch( err => {
            throw new Error( `Cannot connect to barrier: ${err}` );
        } );
};

const connecToBarrier = function ( connectOpts ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        //connectOpts is an object with 'port' and 'host'
        socket = net.createConnection( connectOpts, () => {
            //once I receive a 'hello world' from the machine, I can continue
            socket.once( "data", () => resolve() );
        } );

        socket.on( "connection", () => {
            console.log("onConnection says we have someone!");
        } );

        socket.on( "error", err => {
            console.log(`onError says: ${err}`);
            reject(err);
        } );

        socket.on( "timeout", () => {
            console.log("onTimeout says nothing");
            reject();
        } );

        socket.on( "end", () => {
            console.log("onEnd says nothing");
            reject();
        } );

        socket.on( "close", err => {
            console.log(`onClose says: ${err}`);
            reject(err);
        } );
    } );
};


start();
```

### Research

@robertklep mentioned the `setKeepAlive` option, however according to

[How to test socket.setKeepAlive in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561596/how-to-test-socket-setkeepalive-in-nodejs)

it doesn't work. A more profound research shows that this is highly dependant on the Operative System you are using, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/18678494/1337392

So in other words, unless I am willing to wait several minutes for my heartbeats to actually do something, I don't see a way out of this.

### Question

How do I detect if a connection died?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an interesting read: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

Note in particular this remark:

> It is important to note that the act of receiving data is completely passive in TCP; a socket that only reads cannot detect a dropped connection.

This is exactly what's happening in your case: your socket is waiting for new data to arrive, which never happens. Some OS'es, in particular of the UNIX type, may wait a very long time before they start invalidating open connections if a network interface went down.

The article also proposes a solution that may work on Node.js: enabling TCP Keepalive. This will periodically send packets to the peer to check if the connection is still working.

To enable this on your sockets:

```
socket.setKeepalive(true, 5000);
```

This will start checking the connection 5 seconds after it has received the last packet. More info here: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay

Comment: What what happens if the connection falls meanwhile? Which net.Socket even will be triggered?

Comment: According to the above code, no event is ever fired !

Comment: it appears `setKeepAlive` is not reliable in Node.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561596/how-to-test-socket-setkeepalive-in-nodejs  ... great, just what I needed. Nice try though, kudos++ for help! Also, it is nice to see you again :D

Comment: Well, it depends on your OS settings at which point it will consider the connection to be dead. For Linux, it may still take 11 minutes before it will stop sending keep-alives and declare the connection to be dead. You can decrease that time, though: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html What `setKeepAlive` does is decrease the default "wait period" after which the kernel starts sending the keep-alive packets (which on Linux is 2 hours...)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I ended up doing this as a fix:

```js
const _connect = () => {
  const socket = new net.Socket();
    socket.connect(this.port, this.host);
    socket.setTimeout(10000);

    socket.on('timeout', () => {
        socket.destroy();
        _connect(); 
    });
}
```